# How to find total size of each disk attached to Azure Linux Virtual Machine from Azure Log analytics?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine, disk, azure-log-analytics

I have resource logs of metrics of Azure Linux VM's collected in Azure Log Analytics. Some of the metrics are **% Used Space** , **Free Megabytes** etc.
I get the logs of these metrics at partition level.(/home,/boot,/opt,/tmp,/mnt etc..)

A sample record which has **Timestamp, VM name, Metric Name, Metric Value, Partition name** as fields:

[image]

I want to calculate the total disk size of each data disk attached to the VM from these Metrics.
I've tried this formula:

TotalSizeInMb = (Free Megabytes/(100- **% Used Space**)) * 100

I guess, I get the total size per each partition like /home,/boot,/mnt,/tmp etc.
I cannot associate these partitions to an OS disk or data disk in Azure.

Ideally, i want to find the total size of OS disk and Data disks from metrics in Log analytics.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor/help-with-disk-query-in-log-analytics/m-p/160454/highlight/true#M670) ?

Comment: @amitd Yeah, I have checked that. But that is related to disks attached to Windows VM which will generate metrics per each disk in Log analytics. It's not the same in case of Linux VM which generates metrics per partitions within a disk. I am trying to find out how to find total size of disks attached to a Linux Vm from the metrics that are available within Log analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below query to find the total size of each disk in GB :

```
let disk_free_GB = 
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Logical Disk"
| where CounterName == "Free Megabytes"
| where InstanceName != "/boot/efi" and InstanceName != "_Total" //excluding partitions and total vm space
| summarize (TimeGenerated, disk_free_gb)=arg_max(TimeGenerated, CounterValue/1024) by Computer, InstanceName;
let used_space_percent = 
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Logical Disk"
| where CounterName == "% Used Space"
| where InstanceName != "/boot/efi" and InstanceName != "_Total" //excluding partitions and total vm space
| summarize (TimeGenerated, Used_Space_Percent)=arg_max(TimeGenerated, CounterValue) by Computer, InstanceName;
disk_free_GB 
| join (
   used_space_percent 
) on Computer, InstanceName
| extend  total_gb = disk_free_gb/(1-Used_Space_Percent/100)
| project Computer, InstanceName, disk_free_gb, Used_Space_Percent, total_gb
```

**The expected output is** :

[image]